# How to disable throttling in Lighthouse programmaticaly?

Tags: node.js, lighthouse

As per question title, how can I disable any throttling when using Lighthouse programmatically in NodeJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For v3 it's not working like this but as described here

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/v3/migration

e.g. like:

```
let opts = {
    ...
    throttlingMethod: 'provided',
    throttling: {   
        throughputKbps: 8000,
        downloadThroughputKbps: 8000,
        uploadThroughputKbps: 2000
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

this should help :(tested on lighthouse 2.9.4 )

```
 lhr = await lighthouse(url, {
  port: (new URL(browser.wsEndpoint())).port,
  output: 'json',
  logLevel: 'info',

  disableDeviceEmulation: true, 
  disableCpuThrottling: true, 
  disableNetworkThrottling: true

});
```